# Android R file and Java Sub-package: R can not be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, eclipse, package, java-package

To better organize my classes, I made a few sub-packages (that is an extension in the package's hierarchical name structure).

But to my surprise I have been getting an `R cannot be resolved to a variable` for like every resource I am trying to use from this project's R file.

The Eclipse's quick fixes options do give the option of *importing the particular `R file` for the package (which contains the sub-packages)*, But the question is that in the package that I created in the Eclipse's `New Application Project` wizard, I did not need to import the `R file` at all, and I always thought it contained the resources for this entire project.

But now after creating sub-packages, I need to import it. **SO asking out of curiosity, since a sub-package is nothing (in Java) but an extension in the hierarchical name structure of the package itself ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13809713/java-package-in-package)), then why doesn't the `R file` automatically get included in the sub-packages?**

Comment: Downvoter: I need to know why am I getting a downvote on this, please?

Comment: I am not the "downvoter" but I think because they probably think it's a bad question because it's solved so easily. I'm still a beginner to Android so yeah...

Comment: There is no such thing as "sub-packages" as each package is its own namespace. `my.project.package` is separate from `my.project.package.hello` they are not the same thing, but they may be shown in hierarchy for convenience of viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R` is just a class like any other class (except that Eclipse creates it for you and keeps it updated with your resource IDs).

It is contained in a package - like every other class.

If you want to use it from a different package, you must import it or use the fully qualified name - like you would with any other class.