# Java 9 sub-packages split across modules

Tags: java, java-9, java-module

In Java 9, can I split sub-packages across modules? For example, can I have `com.example.foo` in one module and `com.example.foo.bar` in another module?

This seems like a simple question, but for some reason I'm not able to find a direct answer after some searching. An authoritative reference would be appreciated.

I assume I can have sibling sub-packages in different modules, e.g. `com.example.foo` and `com.example.other`.

Comment: Maybe trying this could be worth it, execute [`getPackages()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Package.html#getPackages--) and you would find them as two different packages. To my knowledge, there is no convention such as sub-package in the JavaDocs either.

Comment: IMHO, this tends to be a duplicate as marked unless specified for any such difference found in the implementations of packages in the mentioned version.

Answer (score 8):

There's no such thing as a "sub-package". `my.package` and `my.package.sub` have nothing more in common than any two random packages: they just have similar names. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13809842/1898563) which starts

> In reality there is no such thing as a sub-package in Java

That being the case, yes you can include them in different modules.

Comment: I am aware that this is the traditional view of packages, but I want to confirm that this conception is still valid after the introduction of the module system, which invalidated a lot of assumptions that had been in place in previous versions. Do you have an authoritative reference that takes the new module system into account?

Comment: The module system doesn't change any of the semantics of packages, and I don't know why you're under the impression that it would. What you're proposing doesn't really make sense because two **distinct** modules should not need to contain **related** packages, but there's nothing to stop you from doing so.

Comment: I am not "under the impression that it would". That's why I asked the question: I didn't know. Thanks for helping to clarify.

Comment: While I respect the fair point that "there's no such thing as a sub-package," I think it's legitimate, for someone who doesn't understand the full spec, to ask this question and expect an answer with references to documentation or a working example. Marking this as a duplicate of a completely unrelated question, closing it from further answers, is, in my opinion, also not helpful (that's on nullpointer, not Michael). It was suggested that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54370999 is a duplicated of this question, but since this question has been closed, I have added a detailed answer there.