# Can one Java module export a package whose name is a subpackage of a package from another module?

Tags: java, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system, java-package

So I know that, in Java 9 modules (Project Jigsaw), split packages are not allowed. That is, the following modules couldn't both export a package with the same name and also be used at the same time at run time:

**Module 1**

```
module com.example.foo {
    exports com.example.foo;
}
```

**Module 2**

```
module com.example.foo {
    exports com.example.foo;
}
```

Not allowed (or, at least, they can't run at the same time). But what isn't clear to me is how subpackages come in to play. If one module exports package `com.example.foo`, can another package export `com.example.foo.bar`? For example, I want to do the following:

**Module 1**

```
module com.example.foo {
    exports com.example.foo;
    exports com.example.foo.exceptions;
    exports com.example.foo.util;
}
```

**Module 2**

```
module com.example.foo.impl1 {
    requires com.example.foo;
    exports com.example.foo.impl1;
}
```

**Module 3**

```
module com.example.foo.impl2 {
    requires com.example.foo;
    exports com.example.foo.impl2;
}
```

Is this allowed? Will all three modules be able to be used together at runtime? Or does the fact that module `com.example.foo` exports `com.example.foo` preclude another module (`com.example.foo.impl1`) from exporting a package with a subpackage name (`com.example.foo.impl1`)?

Comment: When i have question like this i just try it and see if it works.... :)

Comment: Indeed. I didn't see that question after searching for about an hour, and I could see an argument for this being a duplicate of that. On the other hand, that question does not really have what I would consider an answer. What the alleged answer says _sounds_ right, and it was what I thought as well, but I would sure like to see some kind of authoritative documentation on this matter.

Comment: As Roddy says, I may have to just try it out. Unfortunately, creating a multi-module "hello world" (for lack of a better description) project is far less trivial than a traditional single-module/pre-module "hello world." It would actually take a bit of time, and I thought asking here might be quicker.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas and Alexey, I have created a real, working example and posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2):

At @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas suggestion, I created a multi-module sample project to demonstrate the behavior here. The tl;dr is that it works! You can, indeed, do this. To prove out that I was also using modules correctly, I tried the first thing that I knew wouldn't work, and I indeed got errors that prevent it from running.

I have created [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/beamerblvd/dd44652eca5fcca9722e3e630ee8aee2), where you can see the full source code (I will never delete it), which shows how I set up the project. Underscores in the gist filenames indicate directories (you can't use slashes). The project is laid out as follows:

```
- root
  - com-example-foo
    - src
      - module-info.java
      - com
        - example
          - foo
            - SalutationProvider.java
  - com-example-foo-impl1
    - src
      - module-info.java
      - com
        - example
          - foo
            - implone
              - StandardOutHelloer.java
  - com-example-foo-impl2
    - src
      - module-info.java
      - com
        - example
          - foo
            - impltwo
              - StandardErrHelloer.java
```

It compiles fine, and then here is the result of running it:

```
$ java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p out/production/com-example-foo-impl1:out/production/com-example-foo -m com.example.foo.implone/com.example.foo.implone.StandardOutHelloer
Hello, World!

$ echo $?
0

$ java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -p out/production/com-example-foo-impl2:out/production/com-example-foo -m com.example.foo.impltwo/com.example.foo.impltwo.StandardErrHelloer
Hello, World!

$ echo $?
15
```

I believe this should be the answer of the linked duplicate question, because the existing answer just says "there's no such thing as sub-packages" without providing any working examples or documentation that says this is explicitly allowed. However, since the linked duplicate question is, itself, marked as a duplicate of an unrelated question about sub-packages, I can't post this answer there (it's a closed question). As such, I'm posting it here.

Comment: I've reopened the other question. Delete this and post it there. The solution to questions being closed is **not** to create an exact duplicate... That just makes it harder to find information because it's split across multiple questions.

Comment: So, yes or no, is it allowed? This answer does not explicitly actually answer the question.