# How to make a method accessible in all sub-packages

Tags: java, package

Maybe I am using the package concept wrong but I have made a package which has all the classes with common Bluetooth behavior and then sub packages with classes for SPP, HDP, and BTLE. Now what I would like to do is access methods in the classes in the common Bluetooth package in all the sub packages without making it public.

One way to do that is to extend classes but that runs into problems due to my need for Android Contexts and BroadcastReceivers.

I could do what I want if I put all the classes into a single package but that is not quite as nicely organized.

Comment: Packages in Java don't have that concept. You should probably use **modules** for that.

Comment: If you want to call methods from out side the package you have to make them public. otherwise you have to use reflection, it is not nice

Comment: Already answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967229/java-subpackage-visibility

Comment: Yes it is a duplicate. I did not select the correct search parameters to find it....and the answer appears to be as I feared. I am ignorant of the 'modules' concept so that may provide some solution

Comment: @gaurav thank you for providing the link. I wish the moderators would follow your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Java there is no concept of a subpackage. Even if you create packages inside a package. All of these are separate packages. You won't get any advantage out of it.

Comment: Not strictly true.  Java has subpackages per the JLS, but they do nothing other than add some naming constraints preventing classes from sharing the same name as the subpackage.  In particular, as you mention, they don't confer any special access relation between them. — https://stackoverflow.com/a/59956720/1108305