# How to organize code logically into package while preserving encapsulation

Tags: java, java-package

This is a conceptual question.
I usually organize code in packages logically.
E.g.: math operation goes in `my.package.math` or business logic goes into `my.package.business` and so on.

In these days I have a doubt that I want to share about a constraint imposed by the **package visibility** in java.

Let me show some code to explain better my case:
I have the following package structure:

```
+-- org.example
    +-- greetings
    |   +-- RandomGreetings
    +-- GreetingsService
    |
    +-- Main
```

and the following code:

**GreetingsService.java**

```java
package org.example;

import org.example.greetings.RandomGreetings;

public class GreetingsService {
    public String greetingsToTheWorld(){
        RandomGreetings greetings = new RandomGreetings();
        return greetings.say() + " World";
    }
}
```

**RandomGreetings.java**

```java
package org.example.greetings;

import java.util.Random;

class RandomGreetings {
    public String say() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int value = rand.nextInt(2);
        return value==0 ? "Hello" : "Hi";
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```java
package org.example;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GreetingsService sayHelloService = new GreetingsService();
        System.out.println(sayHelloService.greetingsToTheWorld());
    }
}
```

This code, as I show you, doesn't compile because the class `RandomGreetings` is package visible that means that GreetingsService can't instantiate it.
This problem can be solved put **public** in the class `RandomGreetings`:

```java
public class GreetingsService {
...
}
```

But `RandomGreetings` for me is an implementation that I want to keep encapsulation and not public visible.
In this scenario, the world (anyone that import the jar artifact the I may produce) is able to see and call that class and that is not something that I want.

Another possible solution is to move `GreetingsService` at the same level of RandomGreetings, like so:

```
+-- org.example
    +-- greetings
    |   +-- RandomGreetings
    |   |
    |   +-- GreetingsService
    |
    +-- Main
```

In this case, the code compiles successfully and the `RandomGreetings` is encapsulated but I end up with another problem for me.
I not more able to organize that class in the package in a logical order.
In this case, there are a few class so the situation is still manageable but if the number of class increase there will be only a unique big package I think.

I know that in Java there is not [subpackage visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967229/java-subpackage-visibility), so how do you manage that situation?
How do you would solve the problem of my code above?

Comment: Can you check your source code and question text? You say that your `RandomGreetings` class is package visible, but the source code shows it is `public`. And the `GreetingsService` class should be `public` but isn't (or should). Which class do you want to use in the `main()` method? This class has to be `public`. The other classes in the package doesn't need to be `public`.

Comment: I fixed the code. Thanks for the check. `RandomGreetings` is package visible and `GreetingsService` is public.

Comment: Are you looking for something called "Dependency Injection" or "IoC containers"?

Comment: I don't think DI will solve the problem. I can't inject any `RandomGreetings` 
inside `GreetingsService` because I can't instantiate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to use a package, it must have some entry point, which has to be `public`. Otherwise you can throw the package away since it can't be used. This means your `org.example.greetings` package must have something, that is `public` and can be used/called from "outside". It doesn't have to be your `RandomGreetings` class.

You can define an interface (in the `org.example` package), implement it in your `RandomGreetings` class and use another `public` method to create and return the "package visible" `RandomGreetings` class. The code might look like this:

```
package org.example;

public interface Greeting {
    public String say();
}
```

This gets implemented by the `RandomGreetings` class:

```
package org.example.greetings;

import org.example.Greeting;

class RandomGreetings implements Greeting {
    // ...
}
```

Then you define a `public` helper class to return a `RandomGreetings` object from the `org.example.greetings` package:

```
package org.example.greetings;

import org.example.Greeting;

public GeneratorHelper {
    public static Greeting buildIt() {
         return new RandomGreetings();
    }
}
```

When you use the `GeneratorHelper.buildIt()` method you get some object that implements the `Greeting` interface. But you cannot access the `RandomGreetings` class itself because it is still "package visible".